# does Stopself() when used in service stop's the repeating service completely?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

This is how im starting a repeating service.

```
  Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, SyncService.class);
  final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.
  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  long interval = 60000;
  final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context,
  0,serviceIntent,0);
  alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP ,
  System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pending);
```

and this is my service
      public class SyncService extends IntentService {

```
   public SyncService() {
    super("SyncService"); 
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {



    SyncToServer();
    SyncData();
    SyncTrackData();
    stopself();---------> will this stop the repeating service?

 }
}
```

Comment: there is no need to call stopself. You are using a intent service which takes care when the operation is over. Quoting docs Stops the service after all start requests have been handled, so you never have to call stopSelf()

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan.